# Update index template regularly like logstash by terraform

Tags: elasticsearch, terraform, logstash

For example in logstash we have next option for update index template regularly (in output plugin)

```
elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["${elasticsearch}:${elasticsearch_port}"]
            index => "v2-documents"
            template => "/local/template/template.json"
            template_name => "document"
            manage_template => true
            template_overwrite => true
        }
```

by option template_overwrite by template name

Let's say I want to add template without logstash, but with terraform like this

```
resource "elasticstack_elasticsearch_index_template" "document" {
  name     = "document"

  index_patterns = ["v2-documents"]

  template {
    settings = jsonencode({
      number_of_shards = 1
      index = {
        default_pipeline = "routing-ingest-pipeline"
      }
    })
    alias {
      name = "documents-"
    }
    mappings = file("/local/template/template.json")
  }
  version = 1
}
```

In settings section I did some change (for example, add ingest pipeline), but when I replace logstash and manage this template by terraform, changes have not been applied (ingest pipeline was not added). I know that in logstash it is managed by option template_overwrite, how I can same things by terraform?

Answer (score 0):

In the block

> index_patterns = ["v2-documents"]

Please use the wildcard instead, like `index_patterns = ["v2-documents-*"]`.
The template will apply for all indices start with **v2-documents*, ex: v2-documents-001, v2-documents-sample ...
[image]
[Terraform: elasticsearch_index_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/elastic/elasticstack/latest/docs/resources/elasticsearch_index_template#index_patterns)